# Link library in Visual Studio, why two different ways?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, linker

I need to link library from one project into another, and it looks there are 2 ways, can you tell what is the difference and what is the consequence of having "true" in one setting and "false" in another (the same) setting?:

[image]

and another one:
[image]

What is the difference, and do I need both setting set to "yes" or just one and if so which one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A one-line explanation would probably be that the second option specifies something about how the first one works.

- *Link Library Dependencies* set to *Yes*: if the solution is set up so that the current project has a dependency on another project that produces a `.lib` file, then that file will be linked in automatically.
- *Use Library Dependency Inputs* set to *Yes*: useful when *Incremental Linking* is enabled. Normally, if a `.lib` generated by another project changes, and the current project depends on it, the linker can no longer link the current project incrementally (it's difficult for it to know how exactly the `.lib` changed). If you set this option to *Yes*, then the linker doesn't use the `.lib` file generated for the other project, but rather the individual `.obj` files that were used by the librarian to generate that `.lib` (as if the `.lib` didn't exist, and every object file from the other project were given to the linker individually, alongside the `.obj` files from the current project). This enables it to continue linking incrementally when faced with changes in `.lib` dependencies.

As far as I can tell, *Use Library Dependency Inputs* only makes sense if *Enable Incremental Linking* is also set to *Yes*, and the current project depends on another project that generates a `.lib` file that changes often during development.

Conversely, *Enable Incremental Linking* can be set to *Yes* without enabling *Use Library Dependency Inputs*, in which case the project will be linked incrementally as long as `.lib` dependencies don't change; when such a change occurs, the linker will fall back to a full link for that particular build.

Additional information [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/the-visual-c-linker-best-practices-developer-iteration/#linking-libs) and reference docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-property-pages#link-library-dependencies).

---

UPDATE based on OP's comment:

As far as I can tell, the property entry under *Project Reference Properties* specifies the setting individually for each referenced project (whether to use the `.lib` from that specific project or not), while the one under *Linker - General* is the default setting for referenced projects.

For example, if you set the one under *Linker - General* to *No* and add a new referenced project, then, *for that project*, the setting under *Project Reference Properties* will default to *False*. However, the settings for referenced projects that were added before keep their individual setting.

I expect the individual setting under *Project Reference Properties* to override the default from *Linker - General*, but I haven't actually tested this bit.

Comment: sorry bogdan, but my question is not: the difference between "use library dependencies" and "link library dependencies", I'm asking why "link library dependencies" can be set on 2 different places. thanks!

Comment: :-) You selected both settings in red in the second screenshot, and almost selected the other one in the first - that led me astray. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, I'm experimenting now, also it looks if referenced project is not inside the solution one needs to use "linker general" setting, but in that case "Link library dependecies" under "linker general" has no effect for some reason

Comment: @codekiddy As far as I know, dependencies between projects work only within one solution. You can't add a project from outside the solution using *Add New Reference...* in there.

Comment: @codekiddy If your project depends on a `.lib` that is generated outside of the current solution, then you'll need to use the *Additional Library Directories* under *Linker - General* or *Additional Dependencies* under *Linker - Inputs* (possibly both, depending on how things are set up), just like you'd do for any third party library that you need to link to. In that case, neither of the two options we talked about has any effect.

Comment: @codekiddy The two options we talked about are only intended to help you by pretty much doing what I mentioned in my previous comment automatically, based on VS's project-reference system within a solution, but they can only work for projects within the solution.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable inputs! yes obviously setting "use library inputs" to NO has no effect once you manually type library name :)

Comment: Just FYI: incremental linking is very much possible without this active. You make it sound a little as if this is a prerequisite to incremental linking.

Comment: @0xC0000022L I've added a paragraph to clarify that (hopefully). Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't want to hijack the [existing excellent answer by bogdan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28234224/476371), I wanted to add one minor aspect.

The above settings exists in the `.vcxproj` file inside an `ItemDefinitionGroup`, keyed to a particular project configuration.

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='...|...'">
  <ProjectReference>
    <LinkLibraryDependencies>true</LinkLibraryDependencies>
    <UseLibraryDependencyInputs>false</UseLibraryDependencyInputs>
  </ProjectReference>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

As one would think, the value here can be `true` or `false` for the two item definitions. The item definition group establishes the default settings for tasks within a project file. So this establishes the settings for the `ProjectReference` task. Consequently an `ItemGroup` for `ProjectReference` also follows further down in the `.vcxproj`, listing the actual project dependencies with GUID etc.

I always find it useful to be able to match the setting in the IDE to the XML element in the project files, because it enables me to grep for the settings across entire directory hierarchies.

Hope someone else find it as useful.

PS: Unlike most "tool" settings in an `ItemDefinitionGroup`, `LinkLibraryDependencies` doesn't correspond to a command line switch. Instead it's MSBuild that conveys the list of compiler outputs between the dependent projects. `UseLibraryDependencyInputs` on the other end becomes the name of the library dependency on the linker command line in the current project.